# Displaying "amount paid" was not enough on Change Calculator, VB VS2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am new to VB and for a class project we are to make a change calculator, similar to the one that a question was asked on here before. I have an amount owed and amount paid label and textbox. If the amount owned is greater than the amount paid, the program should display  message to remind the customer and tell them how much more to pay.

I figured it out, but the amount that is still due that is displayed in the message is -1.

Example:
Amount Owed: 25
Amount Paid:10
  The message will read, The amount paid is less than what is owed. Please pay $ -1 more.

I'm not sure what I've done wrong, and I'm stuck. Any help will be appreciated!

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1
Dim AmountPaid As Double
Dim AmountOwed As Double


Private Sub CalculateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles       CalculateButton.Click
    'input amount owed from OwedMaskedTextBox
    'input paid amount from PaidTextBox
    AmountOwed = Convert.ToDouble(OwedTextBox.Text)
    AmountPaid = Convert.ToDouble(PaidTextBox.Text)


    'calculate difference of amount owed and paid
    'display an alert message if paid amount is less than what is owed
    Dim dif As Double
    Dim result As Double = 0

    result = CDbl(AmountPaid < AmountOwed)


    dif = AmountPaid - AmountOwed
    If CBool(result) Then
        AlertLabel.Text = "Amount paid is less than what is owed." &
            "Please pay $ " & result & "  more."

    Else
        AlertLabel.Text = ""
    End If

    'display the result
    'let totallabel change text to display the difference
    TotalLabel.Text = "Change: " &
        dif.ToString()

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in this way

```
'calculate difference of amount owed and paid
'display an alert message if paid amount is less than what is owed
Dim result As Boolean

result = (AmountPaid < AmountOwed)
dif = AmountPaid - AmountOwed
If result Then
  .....
```

The expression `(AmountPaid < AmountOwed)` is a boolean expression and you could assign directly to a boolean variable. Then you could test this boolean before displaying your message.

So there is no need of these conversions that introduce errors.